# Is it possible to replace an iMac Fusion Drive HDD with a bootcamp partition on it with an SSD using migration instead of reinstalling Windows?

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, imac, ssd, fusion-drive

On a late-2015 27" iMac, I have an SSD and a 2 TB HDD as a Fusion Drive, and Windows installed on the HDD with bootcamp. I'd like to replace the HDD with a 2 TB SDD. Is it possible to e.g. Winclone the Windows partition and place it back onto the newly installed SSD, or to connect the old HDD and just transfer the Windows partition onto the new SSD without any trouble? (I have a SATA/IDE-to-USB connector)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never done it in this particular circumstance, but armed with somewhere to mount the new drive while you do this [& belt & braces, a regular Time Machine backup], WinClone & Carbon Copy Cloner, I'd say you can't go wrong. Each of those apps will help you through each part of the process, making sure you get a Recovery Partition etc.
At all times you retain the original drive in its original condition, so you're pretty safe. Swap them over once you're totally happy.

It's the kind of task I've done many times over the years, but I have my Boot Camp on a separate drive entirely, so I don't need to move it around too frequently.

Comment: My only additional comment would be what happens if using Carbon Copy Cloner and the sector sizes are different between the new and old drives. Winclone has [posted this issue](https://twocanoes.com/knowledge-base/image-compatibility-between-older-macs-and-usb-c-macbooks-macbook-pros-fixed/) was fixed starting with Winclone 6.

Comment: @DavidAnderson - Wouldn't that just get sorted out as you formatted it? I know of external drive enclosures that will do this internally & the drive 'breaks' if you remove it & add as an internal, but I wouldn't imagine a simple SATA/USB would affect it in the same way.

Comment: I was only partially successful, as I hadn't used Sysprep in Windows before replacing the HDD (didn't want to reopen the Mac again later) and subsequently couldn't get Windows to start up from anywhere I put it. I salvaged the files and programs as much as I could and just went with a clean installation and file transfer, that's still better than nothing.

Comment: I've never had issues with Windows transfer from one drive to another [or even actually one Mac to another, so long as they were similar types]. My current Boot Camp Windows installation is now in its third Mac [all Mac Pros, but different generations… though that would make them all protected MBR installs, not EFI, of which I have no experience]